# Valgrind error when I insert in the map

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have errors in Valgrind: shortly - Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s).(total 113 error almost the same type)
Problem in this part of the code (line where I insert in the map):

in header file:

```
AVLclass<int,char>*ptr1; 
map<int,AVLtclass<int,char>*>check1;
```

in cpp file:

```
string data, number, order, id, token;
int number_i,number_i2, id_i, order_i, data_i;
float number_f2;
char data_c[2];
vector <string> record;
istringstream ss(line);
//separate number (looks for commas)
while (getline(ss, token, ','))
{
    record.push_back(token);
}

id     = record[0];
order  = record[1];
data   = record[2];
number = record[3];
id_i = atoi(id.c_str());
order_i = atoi(order.c_str());
data_i = atoi(data.c_str());
number_i = atoi(number.c_str());

if ( data_i == 0 && number_i == 0)
{     
    ptr1 = new AVLclass<int,char>;
    ptr1->setId(id_i);
    ptr1->setOrder(order_i);
    ptr1->setData(data_i);
    ptr1->setNumber(number_i);
    check1.insert(pair<int,AVLclass<int,char>*>(id_i,ptr1));  
}
```

When I try to use actual integer number instead of id_i, I have 60 mistakes instead of 113. But I do not see values that are not initialized. I tried many different ways to insert in this map, but it is not working.

Comment: what is data_i and number_i?

Comment: I have the same doubt. Maybe one of data_i or number_i was not initialized?

Comment: I added some code

Comment: Recommendation: use the constructor, not setters, to initialize objects.

Comment: Ok, I will do this, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please use std::stoi instead of atoi. It will manage error if, for exemple, the result in record[0] is incorrect. (And Valgrind should tell you the position of your mistake).

Comment: I can't use C++ 11, only 98(( How else I can fix it?

Comment: Check the content of record after your loop.

Comment: not empty, for example record[0] contains id numbers from input file

Comment: when i check id_i inside of my if statement it is also correct

Comment: @Nik [`std::strtol` gives much better validation of numeric input](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) and is available in older C++ standards. See example at bottom of linked document.

Comment: char *end;
       char substr[2] ;
       strcpy(substr,id.c_str());
       id_i = strtol(substr,&end,10);
        cout <<id_i << endl;      This line prints correct output but errors still here.